# What image preprocessing can I use to make my image google vision OCR work better?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, google-vision

I am using google vision document_text_detection on this image:

[image]

I am trying to read the digits in the middle. Now the google vision API works wonderfully well, but sometimes (understandable) it does not detect the middle number or even the middle 2 numbers.
So I am trying out some image processing so I can feed that to the API and hopefully have better results.

So far I have tried:

```
 ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 110, 255, 0)
 ret2, th3 = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
 blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (1, 1), 0)
 ret3, th4 = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

But those don't make it better, even worse.
So do you guys have an idea of what I might try?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to read the watermark ?

Comment: Only the number in the watermark so the "0529221", sorry for the late reply. 
Te output is slightly better now as one of the bugs in the code was that I cast the string to int to compare but that cast in Python ditches the leading zeros. Still I'd like to find a way to up the results. 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is essentially hopeless. If you can predict the size and position of these characters accurately, maybe template matching can work.